# ld: library not found after unzipping

Tags: c++, xcode, zip, static-libraries

I have zipped my Xcode project source for sharing it with my friend. But after unzipping I get the error like **ld: library not found**

Please help. Let me know if you need any additional details.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely one of your libraries was added to project with relative path which goes outside of zipped folder, or with absolute path which also isn't included into archive.